# Accessing a specific element from a list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to access a specific element from a list in Haskell so I searched online and found the "!!" prelude function. I tried implementing it in the code below:

```
(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a
xs !! n = xs !! n
```

However, I realized that the "!!" prelude function was disabled for the exercise I'm trying to complete so I'm not sure how to implement the function "!!" using other prelude functions.

Comment: Note: if the exercise disabled `!!` then this _could_ mean they want you to implement the function yourself. In that case you should try to do it _actually_ yourself, not let others do it for you! But it could also mean something different: that they don't want you to use the indexing operation (whether imported or self-implemented). Indexing into a list is quite un-idiomatic: it's both unsafe (what if you index past the end?) and slow (needs to traverse all the preceding elements). Try to solve the exercise in a way that avoids indexing altogether.

Comment: In my experience, when you want to access a specific element of a list by index you're usually on the wrong track and should rethink your approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can write `(!!)` directly using recursion.

```
(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a
[] !! _ = error "out of bounds"
(x:_) !! 0 = x
(_:xs) !! n = xs !! (n - 1)
```

The first case is our out-of-bounds case, which fails if the index is greater than the length of the list (for safety, we could also include a check for negative indices, but that's omitted here). The second is the base case, and the third is the recursive step.

The [GHC implementation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#%21%21) of `(!!)` is basically this plus a negative check, written in terms of `foldr` rather than with explicit recursion.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your implementation

```
(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a
xs !! n = xs !! n
```

does not work, is not because the `(!!)` operator is unavailable, but because you here define a function `(!!)` by calling a function `(!!)`. So you define a function in terms of itself. This will result in endless recursion, so get stuck in an infinite loop.

You can define the function yourself, for example with:

```
(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a
xs !! n
  | n < 0 = error "negative index"
  | otherwise = go xs n
  where go (x:_) 0 = x
        go (_:xs) n = go xs (n-1)
        go [] n = error "index too large"
```